# How do I automate the summing of values of a column whose table has a reference towards another one?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on a Uni project and so far I've been able to get nearly everything ready. One thing they haven't taught us in detail were triggers and functions, so I had to improvise and learn by myself.

I have the following setup:

```sql
create table finalproduct(
    id_final_product int primary key,
    price float default 0,
    usage text,
    -- + columns and foreign keys unrelated to the question
);

create table rawmaterials(
    id_product integer primary key,
    material varchar(100),
    price float,
    id_final_product int not null references finalproduct(id_final_product)
        on update cascade
        on delete restrict,
    -- + columns and foreign keys unrelated to the question
);
```

I have values inserted, it's all working fine, however, for automation, I have the following:

```sql
create function autosum_product_price()
returns trigger
as $autosum_product_price$
begin
    update finalproduct set price = sum(rpm.price)
    from finalproduct fpr
    left join rawmaterials rmat on rmat.id_final_product = fpr.id_final_product;
end;
$autosum_product_price$ language plpgsql;

create trigger autosum_product
after update
on rawmaterials
for each row
execute function autosum_product_price();
```

The idea is to have the price of a final product be a sum of the prices of each raw material that references that product. For example:

I add raw materials with IDs 111, 222, and 333, each with the price of 11, referencing one final product with the ID 444. This *should* end up making the final product 444 have a price of 33, but instead it stays at the default value 0.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "add raw materials" I assume you mean an `insert` statement. Well you need to check the documentation for [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). Pay particular attention to *event* parameter, as it controls when the trigger fires (is run). Then look at your trigger definition. I think you will see why you are getting the current results.  

Now have a look at your trigger function. There is nothing especially wrong with it, except a missing  requires element. And that join is just not necessary. Again the documentation to the rescue: see [Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html). You will see you have complete access to copies of the current row being processed. Using these  allows reducing the trigger function to:

```
create function autosum_product_price()
   returns trigger
  language plpgsql
as $autosum_product_price$
begin
    update finalproduct  
       set price = price + new.price
     where id_final_product = new.id_product;
    return new; 
end;
$autosum_product_price$;
```

The above will correctly update `finalproduct` on an insert to `rawmaterials`. It will not, however, work correctly for `update` or `delete`. I leave that as an exercise for you. If you have specific problems then post another question.